# Use Bouncy Castle library with .NET Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, bouncycastle, signature

I’m trying to use [Bouncy Castle v1.7](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device.

I’m trying to execute the following code:

```cs
ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA");
```

### Using the Bouncy Castle binaries

On the Windows Mobile device, the code results in the following exception being thrown:

> "The version of the assembly System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089 cannot be loaded by this version of the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework."

On a classic desktop application (using the whole .NET framework), this code runs without problem.

So I’m guessing there is an incompatibility between Bouncy Castle and the Compact Framework.
However the [Bouncy Castle C# index page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) says “*Source now builds on .NET Compact Framework 1.0*” for version 1.2

### Compiling Bouncy Castle from source-code

I've also tried to compile Bouncy Castle from its source-code.
I've compile it using Visual Studio 2008 (had to convert the project and remove classes linked to the IDEA encryption algorithm that were referenced but missing) with the following compilation symbols: **NET_1_1;NETCF_2_0**

When I reference the DLL resulting from the compilation and run the code mentioned above (on a Device) I get the following exception:

> "Method not found: GetSigner Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SignerUtilities."

This seems really strange since I get IntelliSense in Visual Studio while coding.

Can someone tell me how to get Bouncy Castle running on Compact Framework 3.5 ?

Thanks a lot,
Christophe

Comment: Download the source code of BouncyCastle and compile it for CF 3.5.

Comment: Hi, I already did it, I'll edit my question to clarify this point.

Comment: @Cristophe "without success" says nothing about your actual problem.

Comment: You're right again :) I should have been more explicit in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the required files and [put the SLN/CSPROJ files up on my blog](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/07/28/BouncyCastleCryptoInTheCompactFramework.aspx). I created a very simple test app that successfully created an ISigner implementation instance. This was my consumer code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ctacke, it works ! I see you've added the WindowsCE compilation symbol and removed the Test project from the Solution. Did you do something else ? Thanks again :)

Comment: I built the project from scratch as a CE-targeted CF 3.5 app and then added the NETCF_2_0 definition.  That was about it.

Comment: File can't be found :(