# Does Windows Phone 7.1 support SSL sockets?

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, ssl

I can't find a definitive answer on this, but a the moment I'm guessing not.  If not, is there any possible workaround other than proxying via a server?

By way of interest, I'm just trying to connect to Gmail imap for a small test application...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, WP7.1 does not support SSL sockets.

**Edit**
Typically you would use [`SslStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) to implement SSL over TCP. Unfortunately, `SslStream` is not available in Silverlight or WP7. You have to roll your own (which is a bad idea, but possible), or use a third party library.

As mentioned by Eugene, there's [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php), but that's more than a thousand dollars (minimum, depending on your many license choices) to use in a commercial product. If you're doing this on your own, that's probably too big an upfront cost. If you're doing this for your company, it might be a route to consider.

Another option might be to try to use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) in WP7, however BouncyCastle doesn't currently release WP7 compatible binaries and may rely on framework items not available in WP7. [This blog entry](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-bouncy-castle-on-windows-phone-7.html) implies it might be possible, but will require some tweaking.

If you're a solo dev, I'd recommend at least trying BouncyCastle before considering SecureBlackbox. If you're doing your company's WP7 app offering, start with SecureBlackbox.

Comment: Are you sure? SSL is important for secure communication on Internet and it would be a disaster if Windows Phone doesn't support it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. WP7 doesn't offer SSL sockets. You can do HTTPS over WCF, but you cannot do SSL over sockets.

Answer (score 4):

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) offers SSL support: you can use SSL engine with any transport (including sockets and pigeon mail) or you can use socket-based client component. There's a WP7-specific problem with certificate validation though - as WP7 doesn't let us access system certificates, you would need to have trusted certificates list in your application. Not a big problem with our components (SecureBlackbox includes complete certificate management as well), but you need to be aware about this extra step.

As far as I know, IPWorks by /n Software is offered for Windows Phone Mango, but I don't know exactly what they offer in SSL aspect.

Comment: Given that SslStream is not available in Silverlight or WP7, this may be the best option. I hate directing people toward a commercial product, but OP may have to shell out over a grand if he really wants SSL and doesn't want to roll his own.

Comment: I work for /n software. Our Windows Phone toolkits support a variety of SSL options including FTPS, HTTPS, IMAP/POP/SMTP over SSL, etc. You can find info on this [here](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ssl/)

Answer (score 2):

I did get [Bouncy Castle compiling for CF 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859886/use-bouncy-castle-library-with-net-compact-framework) - it's probably not a stretch to use that work for Windows Phone.

Internally we've been using an internal port of [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) for Compact Framework apps for ages, and it wasn't a difficult port.  I suspect getting that working under Phone also wouldn't be overly difficult.

Comment: I actually like the idea of porting OpenSSL over either of the options I presented. +1 :)

Comment: Yeah, I really should get around to Codeplexing that work - been on my to-do list for about 4 years now....

Comment: Just like every other project I "do". :)

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to give Bouncy Castle a crack first, and if that fails then perhaps look at OpenSSL... but I assume if I can't get the former working then the latter won't be worth attempting!